# Sharing Collectd data with Apache on CentOS (SELinux)

Tags: centos, httpd, selinux, collectd

My CentOS 7 VPS has SELinux enabled and is monitored by Collectd. It uses rrdtool to log the reported data. Pommi released a great solution that made me able to review all data on a webpage called CGP (http://pommi.nethuis.nl/collectd-graph-panel-v0-4/).

The RRD data is stored in /var/lib/collectd/my.host.name

`drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:collectd_var_lib_t:s0 my.host.name`

When I open the CGP page it states
`Error: No Collectd hosts found in /var/lib/collectd/rrd` but when I disable SELinux my host shows up and things work normally. The audit log shows:

The audit.log contains the following entries

`type=AVC msg=audit(1410524820.750:15750): avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=10468 comm="httpd" path="/var/lib/collectd/rrd" dev="dm-0" ino=72430599 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:collectd_var_lib_t:s0 tclass=dir`

and

`type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1410524820.750:15750): arch=c000003e syscall=4 success=no exit=-13 a0=7f093426da68 a1=7fff4fa46ae0 a2=7fff4fa46ae0 a3=1 items=0 ppid=10461 pid=10468 auid=4294967295 uid=48 gid=48 euid=48 suid=48 fsuid=48 egid=48 sgid=48 fsgid=48 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="httpd" exe="/usr/sbin/httpd" subj=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)`

So I thought it would be sufficient to change the context of the /var/lib/collectd/rrd folder and contents to `httpd_sys_content_t`. Now CGP works and shows the host and stats. However, when I restart `collectd` and check the status it says:

```
Sep 12 14:31:31 my.host.name collectd[17910]: stat(/var/lib/collectd/rrd/my.host.name/memory/memory-cached.rrd) failed: Permission denied
Sep 12 14:31:31 my.host.name collectd[17910]: stat(/var/lib/collectd/rrd/my.host.name/memory/memory-free.rrd) failed: Permission denied
Sep 12 14:31:31 my.host.name collectd[17910]: Filter subsystem: Built-in target `write': Dispatching value to all write plugins failed with status -1.
Sep 12 14:31:31 my.host.name collectd[17910]: stat(/var/lib/collectd/rrd/my.host.name/interface-eth0/if_packets.rrd) failed: Permission denied
Sep 12 14:31:31 my.host.name collectd[17910]: Filter subsystem: Built-in target `write': Dispatching value to all write plugins failed with status -1.
Sep 12 14:31:31 my.host.name collectd[17910]: stat(/var/lib/collectd/rrd/my.host.name/interface-eth0/if_octets.rrd) failed: Permission denied
Sep 12 14:31:31 my.host.name collectd[17910]: Filter subsystem: Built-in target `write': Dispatching value to all write plugins failed with status -1.
Sep 12 14:31:31 my.host.name collectd[17910]: Filter subsystem: Built-in target `write': Dispatching value to all write plugins failed with status -1.
Sep 12 14:31:31 my.host.name collectd[17910]: stat(/var/lib/collectd/rrd/my.host.name/cpu-1/cpu-softirq.rrd) failed: Permission denied
Sep 12 14:31:31 my.host.name collectd[17910]: Filter subsystem: Built-in target `write': Dispatching value to all write plugins failed with status -1.
```

How can I set the security context so that both collectd AND httpd can access the content?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set up a selinux policy as described in [the documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Fixing_Problems-Allowing_Access_audit2allow.html)

Here's the gist:

```
[root@collectd ~]# audit2allow -a


#============= httpd_t ==============

allow httpd_t collectd_var_lib_t:dir read;
allow httpd_t collectd_var_lib_t:file { read getattr open };
```

(this is the final iteration after running the next commands around 3 times and clicking around in CGP, since each iteration needed more access)

```
[root@collectd ~]# audit2allow -a -M cgp
******************** IMPORTANT ***********************
To make this policy package active, execute:

semodule -i cgp.pp
```

Run the command, rinse and repeat until you've hammered out all the permission issues.

Comment: audit2allow Was indeed the right tool. Thank you.